# edit button variable missing in ajax/js form

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, forms, if-statement

The variables to note are `title` and `category_description`. For context here is my Add feature, both values are correct since it adds to my table.

[image: add]

My problem is my edit button, it shows the `title` data but not the `category_description`. As seen in the screenshot, my description column has a value.

[image: edit]

**AJAX**

```js
$('#addCategory').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  //    var category_id           =   $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  var title = $(e.relatedTarget).data('title');
  var category_description = $(e.relatedTarget).data('category_description');
  //    var category_description_2  =   $(e.relatedTarget).data('category_description');
  var action = $(e.relatedTarget).data('action');

  if (action !== undefined) {

    if (action === "edit") {
      $("#title").removeAttr("readonly");
      $("#category_description").removeAttr("readonly");

      // set modal title
      $(".modal-title").html("Update Category");

      $("#createBtn").text("Update");

      // pass data to input fields
      $("#id_hidden").val(id);
      $("#title").val(title);
      $("#category_description").val(category_description);
      // hide button
      $("#createBtn").removeClass("d-none");
    }
  } else {
    $(".modal-title").html("Add Category");

    // pass data to input fields
    $("#title").removeAttr("readonly");
    $("#title").val("");

    $("#category_description").removeAttr("readonly");
    $("#category_description").val("");

    // hide button
    $("#createBtn").removeClass("d-none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="addCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-center font-weight-bold"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true"> × </span>
              </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" id="postForm">
          <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"> Title <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"> Description <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <textarea name="category_description" id="category_description" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="createBtn" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>
      </div>

      <div class="result"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see from these lines:

```
$("#title").val(title);
$("#category_description").val(category_description);
```

both variables are being declared but only the title shows up. What seems to be missing? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add whatever is needed for a [mcve] - bootstrap or whatever

Comment: not sure how to add a table to a snippet though, im just asking if my variables are correct

Comment: I added bootstrap for you. Now the modal is hidden. You need to at least add the link or button that opens the dialog - so a minimum of one row. Use right-click and inspect to get a copy of a row

Comment: `e.relatedTarget` refers to the button you click to open the modal, which should be the Edit button on the table row. Can you confirm that the data you're trying to read with `var category_description = $(e.relatedTarget).data('category_description');` is not undefined on that target?

Comment: @mplungjan I have already mentioned, my issue is connected to the sql, i dont think i can code snippet a table here

Comment: Of course you can. Right click the table, please beoect, copy html, remove all but three rows and paste in the snippet